# URL Rewrite Rule shows blank page with text

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i'm learning how to rewrite urls and im trying to do that in my ubuntu server. I managed myselft to activate the Allowoverride All and i have htacess working.

I want to change this url for example:

```
http://serverismai/myapi/public/rest/navigate.php
```

And i try to do it like this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^home(.*)$ myapi/public/rest/curso/navigate.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried various solutions but this was the closest i got. The url dosent change automatically but if i insert `http://serverismai/myapi/public/rest/home` i see a blank page with some of my website html written ( not even the html of the page i'm trying to rewite url).

I'm pretty new to this so i want to know if there is something wrong in the Rewrite Rule or if my error is somewhere else...

Thank you!

Comment: What URL do you want your visitors to see what URL should it route to internally?

Comment: I want them to see : http://serverismai/myapi/public/rest/home or would it be even better http://serverismai/home and i want it to route to http://serverismai/myapi/public/rest/navigate.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `/myapi/public/rest/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myapi/public/rest/

RewriteRule ^home/?$ curso/navigate.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Did it but it happens the same thing, i see the html text from another page! My root htacess is in myapi/public/rest right ? Or do i need it to do something in the ubuntu server where i have the virtual hosts? I have read about it but i think it's not there i should make my rewrites...
The thing is that i have in my server 2 services, rest and soap so i guess i shouldnt modified the root server htacess, am i wrong or right ? Thanks for the help

Comment: If it is `/myapi/public/rest/.htaccess` then try my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah now it's working i can acess with the serverismai/myapi/public/rest/home .  The Rewrite rule should be RewriteRule ^home/?$ navigate.php [L,NC] (without curso) btw. Thank you for that. One last thing, the url goes automatically to navigate.php, it dosent change when the user goes to the page but i think that may be because my database links, or is it suppossed to change automatticly with the Rewrite ?

Thank you once again

Comment: Actually this rule isn't changing URL in browser, it is just internally routing it.

Comment: Hmm, okay i'll study a bit more the concepts of the url rewriting, my main goal is to make url links cleaner. I'm marking this as the answers , thanks for the help, this is a good boost for me :)

Comment: You're most welcome and feel free to post a question here anytime you run into another problem